# AWS AppSync - Subscription to a mutation does not return the desired fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, subscription, aws-appsync

I try to subscribe to mutations in a DynamoDB table in AWS AppSync. The schema briefly looks like follows:

```
type Post {
  id: ID!
  userId: String!
  title: String
  body: String!
}
input UpdatePostInput {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  body: String
}
type Mutation {
  updatePost(input: UpdatePostInput!): Post
}
type Subscription {
  onUpdatePost(id: ID!): Post
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updatePost"])
}
```

Given the ID of the post, when I want to get the changes in the body of that post I tried making use of that subscription above as:

```
subscription OnUpdatePost {
  onUpdatePost(id: "some-id") {
    id
    body ## This line should make the trick, but it does not
  }
}
```

The subscription is fired -which is fine. However, the result contains **only the `ID` and `__typename`, NOT the `body`**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "onUpdatePost": {
      "id": "some-id",
      "__typename": "Post"
    }
  }
}
```

Having `body` among the fields should be enough following the guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html).

Am I missing something with this subscription setup?

*Note:*

- The `mutation` works i.e. the body can be updated in the table behind the scenes.
- I did not attach a resolver to the subscription entry, but there is one for the mutation. It should be this way afaik.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Subscriptions in AWS AppSync are invoked as a response to a mutation. Subscriptions are triggered from mutations and [the mutation selection set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html) is sent to subscribers.

I suspect that you aren't returning `body` in your `updatePost` mutation selection set. Add that field and the subscription will contain `body` e.g.

```
mutation {
  updatePost(input: { id: "some-id" }) {
    id
    body
  }
}
```

Comment: That was the thing, perfect! I have never thought of another client's action would affect that directly.

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: One malicious AppSync mutation breaks all subscriptions? What's the best practice here?

Comment: "the mutation selection set is sent to subscribers."  – FYI  This is no longer exactly true since around Nov 2019. You can subscribe to a subset of the mutation's selection set.  You can't however receive a field that isn't in the mutation's selection set, so the solution is still correct.